# How to force object attribute type in javascript and react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have strange problem, with how javascript performs (or in my case doesn't perform) dynamic typing.

I have the following piece of code which will read input from a field, pass it to another function which will assign it as an attribute of *kyselyoikeus*.

```
  <input type="text" id={"kyselykiintioForLupatyyppi_" + this.props.lupatyyppi.lupatyyppi + "_input"}
    value={this.state.kyselykiintio}
    disabled={!kyselyoikeus.kaytossa}
    onChange={(event) => this.handleChangeQueryLimit(event.target.value)}
    className={this.state.invalidKyselykiintio ? "invalidPassivointiTime" : null} />
```

---

```
  handleChangeQueryLimit(kyselykiintio) { 
    this.setState({
      kyselykiintio: kyselykiintio,
      invalidKyselykiintio: !isKyselykiintioValid(kyselykiintio)
    }, () => this.props.changeQueryLimit(this.props.kyselyoikeus, kyselykiintio))
  }
```

Input value should be a whole number, but it is still possible to enter arbitrary string in the input, and it will get assigned to target object property. Only on the validation phase before posting it is checked, that the property is a valid number, with the following piece of code

```
export const isKyselykiintioValid = (kyselykiintio) => {
    // Is a whole number, 0 or more
    return Number(kyselykiintio) === kyselykiintio && kyselykiintio % 1 === 0 && kyselykiintio >= 0
}
```

Now the problem is, even user inputs a whole number, it is assigned to object as a string (value is quoted when I log the object in console), and therefore isKyselykiintioValid returns 0. As far as I know, dynamic type conversion should happen at this point. Why it is not happening? How I ensure that attribute is set as integer if it is integer?

Comment: Wouldn't `parseInt(kyselykiintio,10) == kyselykiintio` be a lot easier if you wanted to check for integers only ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the comparison operator. `===` checks they are actually the same datatype, which indeed is not the case. Solution was to replace it with `==`